# checksum of VS settings-file (user.config) - get path or basestream

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user.config

I am using the internal VS settings functionality. Now I have to ensure, no data is changed outside the designated application, so I want to compute a checksum of the whole xml-file (user.config).

To compute the checksum, I need the path of the file. Is there an opption to get the path or maybe the basestream of the settingsreader or sth else?

Kind regards
Dominic

=====================

The kind of application is Windows-Forms-Application for .net4 environment. I am using VS2013.

Comment: Are you working on Web Application or any other? please mentioned which kind of application do you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information with the following call:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer but this isn't the path I am looking for. I am looking for the pathe of the user.config in Appdata eg C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Company\AppName.vsho_Url_24qxrntjrjy0wlt45fycaljntdotlgom\2.0.0.0\user.config